# Getting Jmeter to generate the boundary dashes in the Content-Type header (eg boundary=--V0a4bfux...)

Tags: jmeter, multipartform-data, multipart, form-data, boundary

This what my HTTP request is generating

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=V0a4bfuxfGhaH_Voo_Gu6oAEtj5FJNcp; charset=UTF-8
```

However, when compared to the POST data, it is lacking the 2 dashes in the front, which causes the server to reject the request:

```
--V0a4bfuxfGhaH_Voo_Gu6oAEtj5FJNcp
Content-Disposition: form-data; data="dataToBeSent"
--V0a4bfuxfGhaH_Voo_Gu6oAEtj5FJNcp--
```

How do I get Jmeter to generate the dashes in the header? 
(besides from manually creating the multipart form)

Note:

- I am using the 'Use multipart/formdata for POST' option.
- If I intercept the request and manually add the dashes in the header, the
  server accepts the request.

Comment: I wasn't able to get JMeter v. 3.3 to generate anything **different** from 2 dashes at the beginning. E.g. with java client: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d159c1302d0y0` with HttpClient4: `--U6pY3zGZBD_bx96zA7CvbGR8kqE_B5ppLF--
` So older version? some other difference?

Comment: @KirilS. I suppose it doesn't need to be exactly 2 dashes. As long as the boundary value in the header matches the value in the POST data. BTW, I was using v3.2. Ideally, it is prefered to have a solution in v3.2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate these values, the solution is to tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or in the HTTP Request Defaults)

If you have any definition of [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header in the [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - you need to **remove it** and let JMeter generate appropriate Content-Type header on its own.

Comment: I am using the multipart form option already, the problem is that the generated value in the header does not have the dashes, while the value in the POST data does.

Comment: I got an issue with uploading data into Flask server. With Postman `multipart/form-data`, it's working fine. But not with the JMeter. As it mentioned in the answer, I removed the Content-Type header in the HTTP Header Manager, then it worked. But now I have to add `Content-Type` header into all other requests, rather having common HTTP Header Manager. @dmitri-t any suggestion on how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1):

The header doesn't need the dashes. This is simply how multipart/form-data works. The body is built as follows:

```
--<boundary>
<headers>

<content>
--<boundary>
<headers>

<content>
--<boundary>--
```

The -- part indicates a new part starts. The body ends with ---- to indicate no new parts will follow.